# React, Redux and Router authentication

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux

Don't know if this is a good question or not. However, I have been searching for hours and I cannot find a satisfactory answer for my problem. To keep things short, in my router, when I route to /dashboard; I want to check if the user is logged in. If the user is not logged in, I want to redirect him to my login page. Only problem, I am receiving my isAuthenticated(is logged in) variable from redux, which takes a second to load. Thus, whenever I check, my variable turns out to be null.

Here is the code,

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Testimonials from "./pages/Testimonials";
import Pricing from "./pages/Pricing";
import Login from "./pages/Login";
import Register from "./pages/Register";
import DashboardHome from "./pages/Dashboard/DashboardHome";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
class AppRouter extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/register">
            <Register />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/login">
            <Login />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/pricing">
            <Pricing />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/testimonials">
            <Testimonials />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/dashboard">
            this.props.isAuthenticated ?<DashboardHome /> :
            <Redirect to="/login" />
          </Route>

          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {})(AppRouter);
```

Much appreciation to anyone who helps out. Still new to react and redux.

Comment: Are you getting the right `isAuthenticated` every time you visit the dashboard?

Comment: Yes. I had a normal if statement so that I was able to run multiple things. And I saw that one time it would print null. Afterwards it would print true / false.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your components `defaultProps`. More info here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#defaultprops

```js
AppRouter.defaultProps = {
  isAuthenticated: false
};
```

*Note:* React's experimental `Suspense` component could be useful to you if you're looking to render a loading component while the user is being authenticated. More info here: https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html

Comment: Hey roasty. Sorry but I fully don't get what you mean. How would setting a default prop help me when I am waiting to receive a response from my redux store? I fully don't understand all this stuff yet so clarifying would help!

Comment: By setting the defaultProps for `isAuthenticated` to `false` you are preventing the user from seeing the dashboard. However, this behavior will be seen even when `isAuthenticated` is `null`. When `isAuthenticated` finally resolves the component should update since the `isAuthenticated` prop is changing. What issue are you seeing now?